# shadowBlur (html canvas) not working in js loop

Tags: html, loops, canvas, shadow, blur

I was trying to improve my stars in the sky animation which I created using JS. This is when i discovered, I could use the shadowBlur property to change the size of the shadow created around my stars, to make it look like they are flickering. The issue now is that the shadowBlur goes up but doesn't go back to black. Here is the code I have used. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated :).

Have a great day!

```js
// ---- Vars for star animation
let randomStars     = [];
let starCollection  = [];
let numberofStars   = 50;
let flickeringStars = 50;

class Star{
    constructor(x,y,color,radius,shadowBlur){
        this._canvas        = document.querySelector('canvas');
        this._canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
        this._canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
        this._c             = this._canvas.getContext('2d');
        this._radius        = radius;

        this._x             = x;
        this._y             = y;
        this._color         = color;  

        this._shadowBlur    = 10;
        this._shadowColor   = 'white';
    }
    //drawing individual stars
    draw(){
        this._c.beginPath();
        this._c.arc(this._x,this._y,this._radius,0,Math.PI * 2,false);
        this._c.fillStyle   = this._color;
        this._c.strokeStyle = 'black';
        this._c.shadowColor = this._shadowColor;
        this._c.shadowBlur  = this._shadowBlur;
        this._c.stroke();
        this._c.fill();
        this._c.closePath();
    }

 
    //Fade in and out for stars
    flicker(){
        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=10;},200);
        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=8;},400);
        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=6;},600);
        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=4;},800);
        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=2;},1000);

        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=0;},1200);
        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=2;},1400);
        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=4;},1600);
        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=6;},1800);
        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=8;},2000);
        setTimeout(()=>{this._shadowBlur=10;},2200);

        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},200);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},400);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},600);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},800);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},1000);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},1200);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},1400);

        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},1600);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},1800);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},2000);
        setTimeout(()=>{this.draw();},2200);
    }

    //Clears the canvas
    clearstars(){
        this._c.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

}


// ---- Functions ----

//Typing animation
const typingAnimation       = ()=>{
        if(textProgress < text.length){
            setTimeout(()=>{requestAnimationFrame(typingAnimation)}, speed);
            if(text.charAt(textProgress) === '\n')document.getElementById('animation-text').innerHTML += '</br>';
            document.getElementById('animation-text').innerHTML += text.charAt(textProgress);
            textProgress ++;
        }else{
            let event      = new CustomEvent('showStars');
            dispatchEvent(event);
        }
}
//Store stars
const storeStars            = ()=>{
    starCollection = [];
    
    for(let i=0;i<numberofStars;i++){
        let x           = Math.floor(Math.random()*window.innerWidth);
        let y           = Math.floor(Math.random()*window.innerHeight);
        starCollection.push(new Star(x,y,"white",(Math.random()+1)-0.7));
    }
}
//Show stars to the screen
const showStars             = ()=>{
    for(let i=0;i<starCollection.length;i++){
        starCollection[i].draw();
    }
}
//Store random stars
const generateRandomStars   = ()=>{
    randomStars = [];

    for(let i=0;i<flickeringStars;i++){
        let x           = Math.floor(Math.random()*window.innerWidth);
        let y           = Math.floor(Math.random()*window.innerHeight);
        randomStars.push(new Star(x,y,"white",(Math.random()+1)-0.7));
    }
}
//Show randoms stars after clearing previous set of flickering stars
const showRandomStars       = ()=>{
    let id = window.setTimeout(function () { }, 0);
    while (id--) {
        window.clearTimeout(id); 
    }

    let starHandler = new Star(0,0,"white",0);
    starHandler.clearstars();
                    
    showStars();
    flickerStars();
}
//Flickers stars and changes set of stars randomly
const flickerStars = ()=>{
    for(let i=0;i<flickeringStars;i++){
        setInterval(()=>{
            randomStars[i].flicker();
        },2200);
        setInterval(()=>{
            console.log("changing stars pattern");
            generateRandomStars();
            showRandomStars();
        },12200);
    }
}


// ---- Event Listeners ----

//Typing animation on load
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    storeStars();
    generateRandomStars();
    showStars();
    flickerStars();  
});

//Handles star animation scaling on window resize
window.addEventListener("resize", ()=>{
    let id = window.setTimeout(function () { }, 0);
    while (id--) {
        window.clearTimeout(id); 
    }

    let starHandler = new Star(0,0,"white",0);
    starHandler.clearstars();

    generateRandomStars();
    storeStars();                
    showStars();
    flickerStars();
});
```

```css
body{
background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body><canvas></canvas></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not work out what FX you are trying to get. Below is a simple flickering star animation that uses small rectangles that change size to simulate flicker.

The frame rate is reduced so that the flicker is more pronounced.

It is very efficient and does not require complex state changes, or slow render methods (like blur)

```js
var W = 0, H = 0; // hold canvas size. Set to zero so first frame sizes canvas
var count = 500;         // number of stars
var frame = 0;           // current frame number
const frameRate = 5;     // render stars ever 5 frames

const sizeRange = 1.5;   // max size of star us minSize + sizeRange + flickerSize
const minSize = 1;       // minimum size of star
const flickerSize = 1;   // amount of change random change to make a star brighter
const flickerRate = 0.1; // odds per rendered frame that a star flickers
const stars = [];

// Create a random set of numbers for star positions.
// Values must be larger than largest canvas you are going to use.
// This will work up to 8K display
while (count--) { stars.push(Math.random() * 1024 * 8) } 

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

function mainLoop() {
  var len = stars.length, i = 0, x = stars[i++], starSize;

  // if the window has resized change the canvas to fit
  if (W !== innerWidth || H !== innerHeight) {
    W = canvas.width = innerWidth;
    H = canvas.height = innerHeight;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    frame = 0;
  }
  if (frame++ % frameRate === 0) {  // only render every frameRate frames
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);            
    ctx.beginPath();  // draw all stars with one path aas it is several orders
                      // of magnitude quicker than creating a path for each
                            
    while (i < len) {
      // draws small stars to large
      const starScale = (i / len);               // set scale from 0 to 1
      starSize = sizeRange;                      // set the range of sizes
      if (Math.random() < flickerRate) {         // on random odds of flicker
        starSize += flickerSize * Math.random(); // add random flicker size
      } 
      starSize *= starScale;   // scale the star
      starSize += minSize;     // add min size of star
      halfSize = starSize / 2; // offset to top left of star

      const y = stars[i++]; // get next random number as star y pos

      // add rect to path fitted to canvas width and height (W, H)
      ctx.rect((x % W) - halfSize , (y % H) - halfSize , starSize , starSize );
      x = y; // Use y for the next x star coordinate

    }
    ctx.fill(); // fill in all the stars
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I had already achieved this look of animation in one of my previous versions of code. For some reason though adding shadow around the stars and making it reduce and increase makes it look a lot more realistic which is why I wanted to workout what's wrong with the current code that I have posted. Once again many thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JohanGodinho The timer events are chaotic and willeventualy crash the page. Timers are far from accurate, and when you have so many it gets worse. In the function `showRandomStars` the while loop  may be iterating tens of thousands of times, and every 12.2 seconds you start 100 interval timers all set to fire at two times. In the example I gave I use an animation loop and control the timing using a frame counter (or several) it is much easier to manage and the timing will be much more accurate.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Sorry I'm just a bit new to js. I noticed how your code has improved performance a lot for me and also requires less resources from the computer. I find it a bit hard to understand the math going on in the while loop though. Would you be able to explain it a little bit?

Comment: @JohanGodinho I have updated the answer by adding comments to the snippet, and changed the variable names to help you work out what it is doing,

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It is very much appreciated :)